# How validate method parameters in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my trying:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :upd
def upd
 unless question_id.nil? || status.nil?
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
 else return true
end

def update_status(question_id, status)
 if question.valid? && status.valid?
   @update = Question.find(question_id)
   @update.update_attributes(:question_status => status)
 end
end

end
```

I get **undefined local variable or method `status'**

Comment: Models shouldn't redirect, controllers should.  You can fix that status invalid error by writing `(status && status.valid?)` instead.  Not sure what your overall intention is.

Comment: about redirect i understand.

Comment: befor update I should check question_id and status parameters which i send from controller

Comment: Is 'status' an attribute of Answer model?. And why are you updating question in answer model? That update_status method should be moved to question model